# JQuery ajax method returning error during POST on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have a web application written in ASP.NET MVC 4. Client side richly uses JQuery to perform requests to save and retrieve data, during the user experience. In certain moments the user can change some data and click a button-like link to save it. For architecture/performance/requirements restrictions, this process is made in two steps:

1. A POST request is sent to the server to a given URL (which will fire a certain action of a certain controller), containing a JSON object;
2. On the first POST success a timer is set to run a second POST to the same server, but different URL (another action in the same controller), with no content at all.

The second POST will just start a complementary process and conclude what was started by the first one. However, it never gets the server. The $.ajax method fires the error handler.

A simplified version of the first request code is

```
$.ajax({
       url: self.opcoes.urlCreate,
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify(lancamento),
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (data) {
           self.LancarDia(250);
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("Não foi possível incluir o lançamento. O servidor retornou\n" +
                          ajaxErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown));
       }
});
```

The method **LancarDia()** receives the miliseconds amount to set the timer for the second request, so the idea is to wait 250 miliseconds and then send the second request. The **LancarDia()** code is:

```
MyClass.prototype.LancarDia = function (milisegundos) {
    var self = this;
    if (milisegundos) {
        if (self.timerLancarDia)
            clearTimeout(self.timerLancarDia);
        self.timerLancarDia = setTimeout(function () {
            self.LancarDia();
            self.timerLancarDia = undefined;
        }, milisegundos);
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: self.opcoes.urlLancarDia + self._dataAtual.format("MM/dd/yyyy"),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (self.opcoes.onLancou)
                self.opcoes.onLancou(self._dataAtual);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var mensagem = "Não foi possível atualizar o MUMPS. Motivo:\n" +
                           ajaxErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert(mensagem);
        }
    });
}
```

Notice that the first POST **always** work and the second **fails many times** but **not always**. When it fails what I get is:

- jqXHR.status == 0
- jqXHR.readystate == 0
- textStatus == "error"
- errorThrown == ""

In its first version, the code didn´t use any timers. On the success of the first POST the second was immediatly sent. Changing to the current implementation was reported to reduce the frequency of the problem, but it still happens.

Only Chrome shows this problem, FireFox and IE run clean.

Have anyone faced and solved this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long study, our infrastructure staff figured out that the problem was caused by the caching policy of the browser (Chrome) and the caching policy configured in the web server (IIS 7).

After configuring IIS to add **no-cache** in the **cache-control** response header, the problem disapeared.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the second `POST` never gets sent to the server, how are you verifying this?  It sounds more like a race condition where the second request is being sent before the server is ready for it (e.g. it is still doing something that was started by the first request).

Comment: It´s simple, I set a breakpoint in the server action and I see it is never hit. However, when the problem doesn't happen, the breakpoint is hit. Considering this, I don´t believe it´s a race condition since the process is basically inserting a row in a ddata server table in the first POST and removing it in the second.

Comment: Are you using a debugger in the browser, such as Firebug or Chrome's development tools?  They'd show you if errors are occuring in Javascript, and also show that the request is being sent